# How does this haskell fragment work? Declaration/Definition Mismatch

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference

Terrible title, but it's the best I could come up with! The code:

```
addInst                        :: [Pred] -> Pred -> EnvTransformer
addInst ps p@(IsIn i _) ce
 | not (defined (classes ce i)) = fail "no class for instance"
 | any (overlap p) qs           = fail "overlapping instance"
 | otherwise                    = return (modify ce i c)
   where its = insts ce i
         qs  = [ q | (_ :=> q) <- its ]
         c   = (super ce i, (ps:=>p) : its)
```

This comes from the article [Typing Haskell in Haskell](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/thih/thih.pdf) (Top of page 15), which explains the algorithm used by HUGS for type checking Haskell 98. Pred is defined as follows:

```
data Pred   = IsIn Id Type
              deriving Eq
```

in the addInst definition, from what I can ascertain, ps is a list of predicates, p is a predicate, and i is the Id field in p; addInst returns an EnvTransformer.

However - and here's where I get lost - the trailing ce appears to be a third argument (a class environment judging by the naming, definition not included here) even though the signature only includes 2 operators.

I'm convinced I've missed something here. Is this some sort of error in the source material or is there some Haskell magic at work here?

### Solution

sepp2k pointed me in the right direction (I actually misread the declaration of EnvTransformer). The two signatures:

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
g :: Int -> (Int -> (Int -> Int))
```

are identical because of, well... currying. Anyhow, if the last argument were an EnvTransformer:

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int -> EnvTransformer
g :: Int -> (Int -> (Int -> EnvTransformer))
h :: Int -> (Int -> (Int -> (ClassEnv -> Maybe ClassEnv)))
j :: Int -> Int -> Int -> ClassEnv -> Maybe ClassEnv
```

... all of these functions take 4 arguments. This is what sepp2k has written, just shown using the parentheses to emphasize how currying is at play in the code fragment and how the type expansion is occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `EnvTransformer` is:

```
type EnvTransformer = ClassEnv → Maybe ClassEnv
```

If we expand this in the signature of `addInst`, we get:

```
addInst                        :: [Pred] -> Pred -> ClassEnv -> Maybe ClassEnv
```

Such a function can in fact accept three arguments.

Comment: Thanks! I'll sheepishly admit I read 'ClassEnv' as a data declaration. I've expanded my question with an 'answer section' to provide some more information just in case someone comes across it. If you could give it your seal of approval, that'd be fantastic.

Comment: @LiamM Answers should go in answers, not in the question! It is perfectly acceptable and even common to answer your own question.